# Python selenium string formatting in web element

Tags: python, string, selenium-webdriver, formatting

How do I iterate over multiple div web elements? I want to collect EPA Registration numbers (ex: 12455-61, 12455-61-3240) using a for loop, but I get error that the web element cannot be located using string formatting.
Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="product">
            <div class="mainSection"><p><span class="reportLabel">EPA Registration #:</span> 12455-61 <a class="link-no-underline" href="http://iaspub.epa.gov/apex/pesticides/f?p=PPLS:102:::NO::P102_REG_NUM:12455-61" target="_blank"><img src="/images/minimal_epalogo.png" alt="EPA logo"></a></p><p><span class="reportLabel">Registration Type:</span>

<div class="product">
            <div class="mainSection"><p><span class="reportLabel">EPA Registration #:</span> 12455-61-3240 </p><p><span class="reportLabel">Registration Type:</span>Section 3 - Regular</p><p><span class="reportLabel">State Product Number:
```

Here's portion of my code:

```
products = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "product")
no_of_results = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="searchResults"]/p[5]')

# //*[@id="searchResults"]/div[1]/div[1]/p[1]/text()  <-- this is the XPATH for EPA# 12455-61, 
# //*[@id="searchResults"]/div[2]/div[1]/p[1]/text()  <-- this is the XPATH for EPA# 12455-61-3240

for i in range(1, int(no_of_results.text[-1])):
    for product in products:
        try:
            """ Find number of products found """
            no_of_results = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="searchResults"]/p[5]')
            "Results:", no_of_results.text[-1]
    
            EPA_reg_no = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="searchResults"]/div[%s]/div[1]/p[1]/text()') % (i)
            "EPA Registration Number:", EPA_reg_no
            print(EPA_reg_no)
            if driver.find_element(By.ID, "searchResults").is_enabled:  # No search results found
                pesticide_table = None
                
            else:
                # more code
                
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            continue
```

I get the error here:

```
EPA_reg_no = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="searchResults"]/div[%s]/div[1]/p[1]/text()') % (i)
```

I also tried doing it like this:

```
EPA_reg_no = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="searchResults"]/div[{}]/div[1]/p[1]/text()').format(i)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To iterate over multiple div web elements and collect the EPA Registration numbers, you can modify your code as follows:

Accessed the .text property of the WebElement returned by driver.find_element() to retrieve the text of the EPA Registration number.

```
EPA_reg_no = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="searchResults"]/div[{}]/div[1]/p[1]/text()'.format(i)).text
```

Comment: Thanks, the output is "EPA Registration #: 12455-61" but I am only interested in "12455-61". I guess I just need to split it now.

Comment: Yes the whole text is "EPA Registration #: 12455-61". Then after if you want the second part you can split it using colon (:)

Answer (score 0):

`find_element` - Returns the first matching web element if the locator discovers multiple web elements

`find_elements` - Returns a list of multiple matching web elements

So you should be using `find_elements` to locate and return multiple elements.

Below code will print all the text within the **EPA Registration #** elements:

```
elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='EPA Registration #:']//parent::p")
for element in elements:
    print(element.text)

# use this for loop if you want to split and keep only the values
for element in elements:
    print(element.text.split(':')[1])
```

**Result:**

```
EPA Registration #: 12455-61
EPA Registration #: 12455-61-3240

12455-61
12455-61-3240
```